# Unable to load Multimaps when added dependency with Apache Hive

Tags: maven, hive, guava

I have added dependency guava for using Multimaps and also I have added Hive dependency in my project.

I am getting the following error while compiling application.

An attempt was made to call the method com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.asMap(Lcom/google/common/collect/ListMultimap;)Ljava/util/Map; but it does not exist. Its class, com.google.common.collect.Multimaps, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/Users/sreenivas/.m2/repository/org/apache/hive/hive-exec/1.2.1/hive-exec-1.2.1.jar!/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.class
jar:file:/Users/sreenivas/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/25.1-jre/guava-25.1-jre.jar!/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
file:/Users/sreenivas/.m2/repository/org/apache/hive/hive-exec/1.2.1/hive-exec-1.2.1.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.

Can anyone suggest me how to take the latest version dependency.

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by the package **hive-exec** include `/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.class`, as shown in picture:

[image]

If you have to include these two jar (hive-exec-1.2.1.jar and guava-25.1-jre.jar), you'd better fix hive-exec's source code and repackage it.